# Computing Conditional Probability: rolling a die

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am facing a problem like this:

> We roll a die with 6 equiprobable outcomes. Compute the conditional probability:
> Pr[outcome is odd ∣ outcome is even]

So by the question, I need to calculate the probability of outcome is odd under the condition outcome is even.

So,

outcome is odd is: 1, 3, 5

outcome is even is: 2, 4, 6

But, as I understand, the outcome is odd and the outcome is even are two events that don't relate to each other(you can only get outcome is odd or outcome is even in each roll).

Do I understand this question correctly? If not then please explain it for me. Thank you very much.
Sorry for bad English, I'm from non-English speaking country.

Comment: Your English is fine!  Just think through the question informally.  If I flip a coin and get Heads, what, then, is the probability that it came up Tails?  That's the same question as yours...

Comment: The answer is 0, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

the probability is obviously zero.

The possible outcomes are the following

$$\Omega=\{2;4;6\}$$

because "we know an even number has been drawn"

As you can see, there are no odd numbers available in your sample space.

Comment: This is the right answer here, thank you very much.